# A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server while migration with asp.net core migration

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I, am using package manager console to perform the database migration.

I used the following command

```
Add-Migration init
```

This command work perfectly and created the migration object as see in the below image[image: migration image]

Now I am using

```
Update-Database
```

command to create the database however I, am getting an error as shown below

[image: error details]

I have used the solution provide [here](http://support.sysonline.com/support/solutions/articles/4000016491-errmsg-a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-connection-to-sql) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci) question.

However, this solution is not working for me from visual studio.

I, am able to use the sql server from SSMS. This error is from visual studio.

Here is the firewall screen shot
[image]

Comment: This solution work for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38705694/add-migration-with-different-assembly

Answer (score 1):

In My Case
**appsettings.Development.json** contain another server Name that was collupse thats why i never noticed .

Comment: Same here. Thanks for the idea to quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

Might be your connection to SQL is not started. Just follow below steps:
1. Go to run command or press Windows+R key and enter services.msc.
2. Find SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) there and right click on it and click on start option. 
Then retry.

Comment: Its start. I am able to browse the database from SSMS. Only from visual studio its not working.

Comment: Just check whether your Visual studio instance is running with Admin rights or not. If not, close visual studio and right click on its icon and then click on 'Run as administrator' and then retry.

Answer (score 0):

This solution work for me.I change the statrtup.cs file as per the below repo

https://github.com/bricelam/Sample-SplitMigrations

[Add migration with different assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38705694/add-migration-with-different-assembly)